# Separate Thread to handle specific API request in cherrypy

Tags: python, python-multithreading, cherrypy

I am using a single threaded cherrypy server(threadpool = 1). I am trying to prioritise a specific request. That's i want a particular api request to be served even if main thread is busy. What are the possibilities to achieve this ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just wondering how you'd serve the promise if two requests hit the same important endpoint, the latest one would prempt the current one if so

Comment: It is a request scheduled for every 10sec. so there are no chance for two or more requests to hit that particular API at a time. Ideally time taken by that API to respond is 5 - 10 milliseconds. Just need a thread for execution.